# Customizing the branding of Azure B2C Device Code UI

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Using the Device code option in Azure AD B2C you are presented with a UI that looks like the following

[image: Azure B2C]

I would like to customize the branding and other UI elements of this page. At the very least I want to replace the Microsoft logo. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

That’s not delivered by AAD B2C, it’s Azure AD, and this can be customised using the AAD Company Branding feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding

Comment: Thank you for the clarity on Azure AD vs B2C. The lines are clearly very blurry. Your suggestion on the branding does not appear to apply to the Device Code screen which is what I am after. See https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/deviceauth Switching common for tenantId or adding ?whr query param are both ignored